# Ошибка "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql

Пытался выполнить запрос к БД и вывести строки из таблицы в тег , но возникает вот такая ошибка:

Ошибка "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"
Версия php: 5.3

Вот мой код:

```
                        $result_set=mysql_query($link,"SELECT 'id','title' FROM 'table_products'");
                        echo"
                        <div class='form-group'>
                        <p>Выберите товар для редактирования</p>
                        <select name='product_number' class='form-control'>";
                        while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['title']."</option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary my-2' name='change-btn' value='Выбрать' /></div>";
                        if(isset($_POST['change-btn']))
                        {
                            $id=$_POST['product_number'];
                            $_SESSION['products_id']=$id;
                            $update=mysql_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `table_products` WHERE `id`='$id'");
                            $row=$update->fetch_assoc();
                        }
```

Строка с указанной ошибкой:

```
while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc())
```

Comment: Надо убрать одинарные кавычки из запроса

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что у `$result_set` есть метод `fetch_assoc()` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon неуместный троллинг

Comment: @Ипатьев, а где у меня троллинг? Я интересуюсь у автора, где он увидел, что у расширения mysql есть возможность писать в ООП стиле. Я такого в документации не видел. В mysqli можно, например, это есть в документации

Comment: А, ты об этом. Да, я не заметил

Comment: @ArchDemon надо было это написать сразу, а не спрашивать. Пока вы отвечали, я переписал код на mysqli и проблема решилась.